# Change route + scrollTo in one click on a Angular page

Tags: angularjs, routes, scrollto

I have a website that has some submenu's with anchors to certain positions on several pages.

So http://127.0.0.1:9000/#/duin#apartments needs to go to "duin" page and do a scrollTo to "apartments" section.

It does not work very well at the moment, only if I'm already on the "duin" page it will do a scrollTo. If it first needs a route change, then it will not.

So from #/duin#apartments to #/location#city will only do a route change to #/location without the scrollTo #city

Comment: You can use `$anchorscroll` to scroll to particular section. I have created demo also http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MajweB. I have also one doubt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099241/angular-with-bootstrap-scrollspy so i attached it to SO

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, not sure if I can still implement such a directive in my site at the moment. Will a ng-href and ng-click both executed? So then I can make a route change via ng-href and execute a funtion call inside ng-click